# Formula not calculating correctly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm experiencing an issue with a formula in JavaScript.

```
var animMoveX = $(this).attr('data-start') + (animPercentage / 100) * ($(this).attr('data-finish') - $(this).attr('data-start'));
```

To my eyes it's a fairly simple piece of math, but the console outputs 120-[variable no relative to animPercentage, eg. 126.49681528662421].

I've double-checked all variables, and they are correct, and if I replace one of the $(this).attr('data-start') variable in one of the positions with a fixed number, then the calculation is run just fine. Can someone shed some light on why this is, and how I could potentially work around it?

Comment: You can use `$(this).data("start")` instead of `$(this).attr("data-start")`

Comment: Precedence means it will calculate a number on the right and add it to the *string* from data-start (i.e. using string concatenation). That needs to be converted to a number too. @Pointy's suggestion will do that as `data` converts strings to appropriate data types (when it can).

Comment: Thanks to both of ya!

Comment: Create a fiddle . looks like you need to convert string into int

Comment: You can also use `*1` to convert strings to ints, eg `.. - ($(this).attr("data-start") * 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment: Precedence means it will calculate a number on the right and add it to the *string* from data-start (i.e. using string concatenation). That needs to be converted to a number too. @Pointy's suggestion will do that as `data` converts strings to appropriate data types (when it can).

So basically change all the attr() calls to data() calls and "numbers" (stored in attributes) will become numbers:

```
var animMoveX = $(this).data('start') + (animPercentage / 100) * ($(this).data('finish') - $(this).data('start'));
```

As an added bonus, using `data` instead of `attr` is shorter code too :)